# как выделеть весь текст в текстовом редакторе онлайн на puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, клавиатура, webbrowser, puppeteer

есть текстовый редактор онлайн на который я захожу через **puppeteer**
задача состоит в том что бы удалить ID у этих скриптов примерно так

`code.replace('myScriptId', '')`

верстку трогать нельзя через *evaluate*
я могу только манипулировать буфером обмена

сценарий я вижу такой

1. выделяю весь код в онлайн редакторе (вообще я разрабатываю в *macos* но работать этот код будет на *ubuntu server*, в macos я это делаю так *command + a* как это сделать в **puppeteer** это и есть главный вопрос)
2. копирую в буфер обмена
3. копирую буфер в переменную и обрабатываю как мне нужно `code.replace('myScriptId', '')`
4. вставляю обработанный код обратно в редактор

возможно ли такое ? как это реализовать и зависит ли это код от *OS*

```
(async () => {
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
        const [ browserPage ] = await browser.pages()
        await browserPage.goto('https://online.code');

        
        const Online_Store = '.Ccode'
        await browserPage.waitForSelector(Online_Store)
        await browserPage.click(Online_Store)
        /** Your code */

        
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('console error: ',error)
        browser.close()
    }
})()
```

как продолжить этот код ?

Comment: Боюсь, без ссылки на сайт с редактором будет трудно делать какие-то предположения.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty  этот редактор из myshopify, там редактируют тему и он работает точно не в iframe

Comment: скорее всего там contenteditable

Comment: там просто див с такой версткой <span class="cm-meta">&lt;!doctype html&gt;</span>  но если ее поменять то она обратно возвращается ее не сохранить так